# Large number of bitwise enums

Tags: objective-c, enums, bit-manipulation

I've got a question regarding bitwise enums that I just can't seem to resolve.  I've got a number of flags that are represented by a bitwise enum as in the following example:

```
enum
{
    EnumNone=0,
    EnumOne = 1<<0,
    EnumTwo = 1<<1,
    EnumThree = 1<<2,
    EnumFour = 1<<3
};
typedef NSUInteger MyEnum;
```

All is fine with the above example.  Based on my research and various helpful posts in stackoverflow ([this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936480/bitwise-or-of-constants)), I've concluded that, using the above example, I'm essentially given 32 options (or shifts if you will), each option representing 1 bit in a 32-bit series of options, which basically tells me that I can go all the way to `EnumThirtyTwo = 1 << 31`.

***My question is this:***

Suppose I've more than 32, say 75 flags for example, to represent using a bitwise enum.  How would that best be represented?

```
enum
{
    EnumNone=0,
    EnumOne = 1<<0,
    EnumTwo = 1<<1,
    EnumThree = 1<<2,
    EnumFour = 1<<3,
    ...
    ...
    EnumSeventyFive = 1<<75
};
typedef NSUInteger MyEnum;
```

Would it be a simple matter of changing the declaration of my enum type, say, to: `typedef long int MyEnum;` or `typedef long MyEnum`?

Comment: If you need to go over 64 flags then you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Thanks @PaulR for your input.  +1 for not making that your answer :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a few simple macros/functions and a `struct` containing a `char` array of sufficient size - gives you *call-by-value* semantics, i.e. just like real enums. E.g. something along the lines of (typed directly into answer):

```
typedef struct
{
    char bits[10]; // enough for 80 bits...
} SeventyFiveFlags;

typedef enum
{
   EnumOne = 0,
   ...
   EnumSeventyFive = 74
} SeventyFiveFlagNames;

NS_INLINE BOOL testFlag(SeventyFiveFlags flags, SeventyFiveFlagNames bit)
{
   return (flags.bits[bit >> 3] & (1 << (bit & 0x7))) != 0;
}
```

However you can also use the bitstring(3) functions/macros if you are OK with *call-by-reference* semantics. These create (heap or stack) bit strings of any length. Use your enum to provide symbolic names for the bit numbers rather than masks, e.g.:

```
#include <bitstring.h>

typedef enum
{
   EnumOne = 0,
   ...
   EnumSeventyFive = 74,
   SeventyFiveFlagsSize = 75
} SeventyFiveFlagNames;

typedef bitstr_t *SeventyFiveFlags;

// local (stack) declaration & use
SeventyFiveFlags seventyFive;
bit_decl(seventyFive, SeventyFiveFlagsSize); // declare
bit_nclear(seventyFive, EnumOne, EnumSeventyFive); // set all false

if( bit_test(seventyFive, EnumFortyTwo) ) // test
```

You can always wrap this up as a class if heap allocation only is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am talking about something irrelevant.

I think having too much flag in an enum is not a good practise. Having this large amount of flag, there must be ways to group them up like:

```
enum
{
    EnumNone=0,
    EnumOne = 1<<0,
    EnumTwo = 1<<1,
    EnumThree = 1<<2,
    EnumFour = 1<<3
};
typedef NSUInteger widthRelated;

enum
{
    EnumNone=0,
    EnumOne = 1<<0,
    EnumTwo = 1<<1,
    EnumThree = 1<<2,
    EnumFour = 1<<3
};
typedef NSUInteger heightRelated;
```